# Efficiently Read First Image for Large Stored Numpy Array Representing Video

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, class, numpy-ndarray

Suppose a numpy nd-array representing a video is stored in the computer . What is the most efficient way to load the first image ?

More precisely, consider the following pseudocode :

```
class MyArray():
    self.array 

def function():
    #some manipulations
    return an object of class MyArray with video.array being a numpy array of shape say (100000,100,100,3)

video = function()
```

Here we assume that `video.array` is an array representing a video. That is, for each `t = 0,1,...,99999`, `video.array[t,:,:,:]` is an RGB image.

Suppose now that we have finished the execution of the above code. Namely, we already have `video` being an object of class `MyArray`. By writing `first_image = video.array[0,:,:,:]`, we can get the first image of the video. But it seems the computer will first read `video.array` (which is slow) and then call the first image.

Question: What is the fastest equivalent of `first_image = video.array[0,:,:,:]`? Is there any sort of, for example, partial read mechanisms in numpy or opencv or any other library?

Clarification:
If, right after the above pseudocode, I write:

```
result = video.array        #Line 1
first_image = result[0]     #Line 2
```

It turns out that, usually, line 1 takes like 10 seconds and line 2 takes like a fraction of second. On the other hand, the command `first_image = video.array[0]` mentionned in the post takes also like 10 seconds. Therefore:

```
The command first_image = video.array[0] always reads the whole video.array and then takes the first image
```

I am asking whether it is possible to not read the entire video. All I need is for it to stop after reading the first image. The present answers therefore do not really answer my question.

Comment: You have an array *"stored in the computer"*. Do you mean in disk? Or in RAM?

Comment: I call it stored in computer because, after execution of code, we get an object of class `MyArray` stored. So no it is not stored as a file in the disk.

Comment: I think you want a *"generator"* that will `yield` a frame, maybe.

Comment: What do you mean by a generator?

Comment: Have a read here... https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/

Comment: Thank you. This indeed looks like what I need. I will study it. I have also updated the question to make things more precise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have answered your own question: If you want to index the first image frame in your numpy array you can just use the index position in the first dimension.

```py
import numpy as np

# frames, bands, rows, cols
shape = (50, 3, 128, 128)

# Random test data of the requested shape.
video_array = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=shape)

first_frame = video_array[0]

first_frame.shape
# (3, 128, 128)
```

It sounds like maybe you are using another library or program that reads the entire array from inside an object, `video`, and upon calling the property `video.array` you are executing a load from disk function?

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple; method to get nth image from the video:

```
class MyArray():
    self.array = ...

    def getframe(self, n):
        return self.array[n]
```

To get first image just call `myarray.getframe(0)` on the object `myarray`.

And if you want to read from file, use count in `np.fromfile`:

```
import time
import numpy as np

W, H, CH = 1920, 1080, 3
N = 1000
random_video = np.random.randint(0, 256, (N, H, W, CH), np.uint8)
print(f"size of video ={random_video.size / 2 ** 30} GB")

FILE = "d:/1.npy"

t0 = time.monotonic()
random_video.tofile(FILE)
t1 = time.monotonic()
print(f"save time={t1 - t0:.3g} s")
## read first frame
FRAMES_TO_READ = 1
SINGLE_FRAME_SIZE = FRAMES_TO_READ * W * H * CH

t0 = time.monotonic()
video = np.fromfile(FILE, np.uint8, count=SINGLE_FRAME_SIZE, offset=0).reshape(FRAMES_TO_READ, H, W, CH)
t1 = time.monotonic()
print(f"read time(single frame)={t1 - t0:.6f} s")

np.array_equal(random_video[0:FRAMES_TO_READ], video)
```